# \twocolumn[{\begin{@twocolumnfalse} explained

Tags: two-column

I'm typesetting a document in the `[twocolumn]` format. I found (Googled) that a way how to place some material spread over both columns is as in the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
  \centerline{\Large\bfseries This is my manually set ``wide'' title}
  \vspace{3ex}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}]

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I would like to:

1. Understand what does the code really do.
2. Ask whether there is a better way how to do that.
3. Get some good documentation with `[twocolumn]` explained.

Comment: The `@twocolumnfalse` isn't necessary to write about the whole line. It's the default behaviour of `\twocolumn[]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting Kopka and Daly, *Guide to LaTeX*, p. 54:

> `\twocolumn[<header text>]`
>
> Terminates the current page, starting a new one with *two columns* per
> page. The optional *header text* is written at the top of the page in
> one column with the width of the whole page.
>
> [...]
>
> The [standard class] option `twocolumn` automatically changes certain
> page style parameters, such as indentation, compared with the
> one-column format. This does not occur with the command `\twocolumn`.
> These additional changes must be made with the corresponding
> `\setlength` declarations if they are desired. If the bulk of the
> document is in two-column format, the class option is to be preferred.

Note that the argument of `\chapter` will also span the width of the whole page in `twocolumn` mode. Using `\chapter` inside the optional argument of `\twocolumn` will produce an error (`Float(s) lost`).

EDIT: According to the [TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs), there *is* at least one case in standard LaTeX where manually switching to `@twocolumnfalse` is useful: One-column abstracts in a two-column `article`. Try to comment out `\begin{@twocolumnfalse}` and `\end{@twocolumnfalse}` in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{abstract}
    \sometext
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\sometext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for some explanation from a book, the problem with `{abstract}` is exactly the reason why I cannot omit `@twocolumnfalse`.

Answer (score 8):

It is the same as:

```
\twocolumn[\@twocolumnfalse
  \centerline{\Large\bfseries This is my manually set ``wide'' title}
  \vspace{3ex}
   ]
```

except that it (ab)uses `\begin` to execute `\csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname` and so avoid messing around with `\makeatletter`.

The optional argument to twocolumn is set in a full width box before the columns start.
the `\@iftwocolumn` is set to false will have no effect in that example but if there were more complicated code in that section then it may test that flag. The only things I can see** in standard latex that test  `\if@twocolumn` are things related to floats and `\clearpage` neither of which are relevant in that position. But there could be other package code that needs to know if it is in full page setting or within a single column.

** As pointed out in chat and @lockstep's answer, the standard classes test this switch in the definition of `\abstract` so abstracts within the optional argument to `\twocolumn` *are* affected by adding the setting of `@twocolumnfalse`.

Comment: Don't forget that `\begin` .. `\end` also adds grouping, keeping the if-switch change local.

Comment: Not on that position as the twocolumn argument is a box so it is already local, that is, it adds group but the group doesn't change the behaviour except for edge cases with `\aftergroup`

Comment: Thanks David for your effort, however, I decided to accept lockstep's answer since he first pointed out what is `@twocolumnfalse` good for. Hope you don't mind.