# How to share a one column figure with two column text on same page

Tags: floats, two-column

I am writing an article that is composed of a two column body. But on one page, I want a figure that takes up both columns at the top and below I want to continue writing in two column text.

So far I have,

```
\newpage
\onecolumn
\subsection{Pumped Hydro}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{operatingprincipal.jpg}
\caption{Pumped Hydro}
\end{figure}
\twocolumn
 {text goes here}
```

what happens here is the text continues on the next page, leaving about 3/4 of a page of blank space below the figure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\twocolumn` starts a new page. You can place a single column figure in a two column document without difficulty, simply by using figure*. The answers to this question should help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/placing-figures-inside-a-two-column-document

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a two column figure you want the * form. remove the `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` and use

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{operatingprincipal.jpg}
\caption{Pumped Hydro}
\end{figure*}
```

(don't use `[h!]` on figures as the main effect of that is to prevent the figure being placed in any available float area and so go to the end of the document. LaTeX issues a warning and changes it to `[!ht]` to at least allow top floats but it still leaves float pages disabled.

As two column floats come at the earliest on the page *after* they appear in the source you may need to move the location of this in your source document.

Comment: well that seems to somewhat work. There appears to be a conflict when using \newpage placed right before the figure, but its a start. I'm going to play around with it and see if I can format it correctly, thanks.