# Placing a minipage or a table on top of the right column

Tags: floats, multicol

I am new to TeX, but I cannot find a solution to my problem anywhere.

I have some text in two columns just after a page wide image (and this is not a problem).

But I would like to add a little table (a sort of a legend, maybe a minipage?) on the top of the right column, as wide as a column.

Is there a way to do it? 
Any suggestion about the packages I should look for?

Thanks in advance,
Fabio

Comment: you have tagged the question multicol but that doesn't support floats, are you using multicol or the `[twocolumn]` document option? In the later case the easiest thing is to have a `table` environment following the `table*` to hold the legend, it may need a bit of manual adjustment of its position in the source file to ensure it floats to the second column.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use multicol because it doesn't force me to start a new page each time I switch from one to two columns.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX doesn't automatically keep the floats together so you have to be careful where you place them in the source but:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a\par Red green blue. \a\a\a\par Yellow black \a\a\a\a}
\def\c{Something \b \b More text here \b\b}
\begin{document}

\c\c\c

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
aaa aa aa aaa a a a aaaaaaaaa&1&bbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&1&bbbb\\
aaaaaaaaaaa&1234567890&bbbbb b b b b bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\c\c\c

\begin{table}
\raggedright\itshape
Some interesting text about the above table.
Some more interesting text about the above table.
Yet more interesting text about the above table.
\end{table}
\c\c\c\c\c\c
\c\c\c\c\c\c\c

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately it looks like that the position of the second table depends on the length of the text between the two tables. The perfect solution for me would be to place the top figure and the legend with an absolute position and then wrap the text around.

Comment: @Fabio unfortunately the world isn't always perfect:-)

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box `multicol` doesn't support floats as David explained due to the fact that it needs to do balancing and that means it is not quite known where material is going to fall.

However if you know that you want a column float on a particular page in a particular column (in other words you are doing something somewhat manual) then my answer in

[Placing figures inside a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/placing-figures-inside-a-two-column-document/57750#57750)

may offer you a solution.

As an alternative you may want to look into applying the `flowfram` package. Again that will require manual setup for your document but it will allow you great control over the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. I will check it as soon as possible.