# Figures with [h] position in multicols environement

Tags: graphics

I usually work with the normal article latex environment, with one column, and I usually introduce figures using the position given by [h] (with means "place the float here, i.e., approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot)".

However, in multicols (in this case, in two columns), the only way I know to introduce graphics is by means of float package and it only works with the position given by [H] ("put exactly here"). The problem is that I have several graphics and using the position given by [H] there are lots of empty spaces that looks quite bad.

The question is if there is some way to use [h] position or something equivalent in the multicols package.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[h]` is usually an error and latex will give a warning and change it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` is better (not including `p` makes it much more likely the float goes to the end of the document). Frank had an answer with a modifiedfigure handling in multicols, I'll see if I can find it..

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/placing-figures-inside-a-two-column-document/57750#57750

Comment: You can't use an unstarred `figure` environment within a `multicols` environment. You can use the starred version but the figure will always be moved to another page. See sections 2.4 and 2.6 of the package's manual.