# `twocolumnfalse` not running onto second page

Tags: two-column, article

I'm writing a two column article and want to have my abstract, ToC, LoF and LoT all spanning both columns.

I can do this by using the `twocolumn` and `twocolumnfalse` environments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan venenatis purus vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis tortor scelerisque, in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend ligula vitae urna viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non pulvinar. Cras augue libero, vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper pretium ligula. Etiam commodo purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec maximus, nibh id posuere tempor, sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae vulputate tortor turpis at diam. Donec mollis efficitur condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius, mattis ex ut, commodo dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur consequat nibh eleifend non. Vestibulum vitae blandit erat. Quisque justo ante, auctor sed rhoncus nec, volutpat id sem. Nam vestibulum, risus sit amet efficitur euismod, libero dui tempus elit, et convallis lectus odio eu dolor. \\\\
        \end{abstract}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
\bigskip]
\end{document}
```

However, the problem arrises due to the fact that my various lists and tables mean this is over a page in length. It doesn't seem to run onto the second page, instead getting clipped. I could fix this manually by separating each list into it's own `twocolumn` environment and adding a manual `newpage` where it fit but that's far from ideal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As always on this site: Post full (but minimal) examples, not just sniplets and expect others to fill in the details. Also since when is `@twocolumnfalse` an environment?

Comment: @daleif, my bad. Added he relevant bits. As for what `@twocolumfalse` should be called you'll have to tell me. I'm certainly no expert.

Comment: @daleif https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57584/twocolumn-begintwocolumnfalse-explained

Comment: @Persistence it really helps people to answer if you provide a useful test file, your example generates an unrelated error (no title), is a single column document and has empty lists of tables so does not overflow the page which is the problem you want help with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup you show is for making a spanning entry *across* the top of the start of two columns.

To set a sequence of pages one column use

```
\onecolumn

your single column pages


\twocolumn

the rest of the book
```

---

Or use `multicols` if you want to start two column mid-page

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{zzz}
\author{Zzzz}
\begin{document}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit. Morbi faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan
          venenatis purus vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor
          quis tortor scelerisque, in molestie turpis
          consequat. Aenean eleifend ligula vitae urna viverra
          cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non pulvinar. Cras augue
          libero, vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper pretium
          ligula. Etiam commodo purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec
          maximus, nibh id posuere tempor, sapien turpis egestas
          tellus, vitae vulputate tortor turpis at diam. Donec mollis
          efficitur condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius, mattis ex
          ut, commodo dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur
          consequat nibh eleifend non. Vestibulum vitae blandit
          erat. Quisque justo ante, auctor sed rhoncus nec, volutpat
          id sem. Nam vestibulum, risus sit amet efficitur euismod,
          libero dui tempus elit, et convallis lectus odio eu
          dolor. %no!\\\\
        \end{abstract}
        \tableofcontents



\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{zzzz}\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan venenatis purus
vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis tortor scelerisque,
in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend ligula vitae urna
viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non pulvinar. Cras augue libero,
vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper pretium ligula. Etiam commodo
purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec maximus, nibh id posuere tempor,
sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae vulputate tortor turpis at
diam. Donec mollis efficitur condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius,
mattis ex ut, commodo dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur
consequat nibh eleifend non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Morbi faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan
venenatis purus vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis
tortor scelerisque, in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend
ligula vitae urna viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non
pulvinar. Cras augue libero, vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper
pretium ligula. Etiam commodo purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec
maximus, nibh id posuere tempor, sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae
vulputate tortor turpis at diam. Donec mollis efficitur
condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius, mattis ex ut, commodo
dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur consequat nibh
eleifend non.
\section{zzzz}\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan venenatis purus
vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis tortor scelerisque,
in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend ligula vitae urna
viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non pulvinar. Cras augue libero,
vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper pretium ligula. Etiam commodo
purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec maximus, nibh id posuere tempor,
sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae vulputate tortor turpis at
diam. Donec mollis efficitur condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius,
mattis ex ut, commodo dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur
consequat nibh eleifend non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Morbi faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan
venenatis purus vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis
tortor scelerisque, in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend
ligula vitae urna viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non
pulvinar. Cras augue libero, vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper
pretium ligula. Etiam commodo purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec
maximus, nibh id posuere tempor, sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae
vulputate tortor turpis at diam. Donec mollis efficitur
condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius, mattis ex ut, commodo
dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur consequat nibh
eleifend non.
\section{zzzz}\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan venenatis purus
vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis tortor scelerisque,
in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend ligula vitae urna
viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non pulvinar. Cras augue libero,
vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper pretium ligula. Etiam commodo
purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec maximus, nibh id posuere tempor,
sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae vulputate tortor turpis at
diam. Donec mollis efficitur condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius,
mattis ex ut, commodo dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur
consequat nibh eleifend non.
\section{zzzz}\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx\subsection{xggg}xxx
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi
faucibus lectus vel porta euismod. Ut accumsan venenatis purus
vestibulum egestas. Phasellus aliquet tortor quis tortor scelerisque,
in molestie turpis consequat. Aenean eleifend ligula vitae urna
viverra cursus. Sed blandit nec ante non pulvinar. Cras augue libero,
vestibulum sed ante eget, ullamcorper pretium ligula. Etiam commodo
purus a lacus cursus dignissim. Donec maximus, nibh id posuere tempor,
sapien turpis egestas tellus, vitae vulputate tortor turpis at
diam. Donec mollis efficitur condimentum. Curabitur id erat varius,
mattis ex ut, commodo dui. Praesent eleifend lacus tellus, consectetur
consequat nibh eleifend non.

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi David, ideally I would like the article to start immediately following the end of the lists rather than requiring a new page. Is this possible?

Comment: If it is less than one page use \twocolumn[stick everything one column here, even if you have to put it into a savebox first.]

Comment: @Persistence given that latex is open source, anything is possible but basically no, not if you use the standard `[twocolumn]` option, if you want to start and stop multicol mid-page use the `multicol` package instead.