# Making a onecolumn abstract the same width as the full twocolumn width

Tags: two-column, abstract, textwidth

Is there a way to make a one column abstract in a two column document be the same width as the following twocolumn text?

This question follows on from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57586/169285).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse} 
    \maketitle 
    \begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your "own abstract". With the following, for instance, you can simulate an abstract.

```
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse} 
    \maketitle 
    \begin{center}
        Abstract
    \end{center}
%    \begin{abstract}
    \hspace{1em}\blindtext 
    \\
%    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

With this code, you lost the semantic meaning of an abstract, but if you won't reference in the table of contents, is a minor problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the `article` class the abstract is set narrower than the textwidth. You could define your own version of `abstract`, say `myabstract` and use that, as below.

```
% onetwocolprob.tex SE 537843

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{myabstract}{%
  \small
  \begin{center} \bfseries Abstract \end{center}%
  }{\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse} 
    \maketitle 
%    \begin{abstract}
    \begin{myabstract}
    \blindtext
    \end{myabstract}
%    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Just a comment; I think that the original narrower abstract looks better.