How do you write a page-centered abstract in a two column document
How do you a report write in two columns, but with an abstract at the beginning that is centred on the page?
I tried using [twocolumn] in documentclass, but that centres the abstract into the left column.
I also tried \begin{multicols}, but the columns don't continue until the end of the page.
Thanks.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal working example to start with.

See e.g here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537843/245790 . Also click on the abstract tag and add twocolumn to browse potential solutions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the document is to be primarily two-column, I prefer to use \twocolumn or the twocolumn class option to multicol, since it avoids some of the complications inherent in code designed to accommodate switches between different column layouts on the same page.
To get a centred abstract, I used the optional argument of \twocolumn[] rather than the twocolumn class option. The 'trick' is to pack both the abstract and \maketitle into the optional argument, which prevents an unwanted page break.
The code below also demonstrates how to redefine the abstract environment to achieve (what I consider) better sizing and spacing: the title is set in normal sized font (here 10pt by default) and bold, while the abstract is uses a smaller size and indentation on both sides. For this the code (mis)uses the quote environment. If your abstract includes multiple paragraphs, you may want to substitute quotation here.
 
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{}
{%
  \begin{center}
    \bfseries\abstractname
  \end{center}%
  \begin{quote}
    \small
}{%
  \end{quote}%
}
\begin{document}
\author{IK}
\title{CPR}
\twocolumn[%
  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    {\kant[1]}
  \end{abstract}%
]
\kant[2-5]
\end{document}


Like this:

Code:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{Title}
\author{The best one}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section{Just to begin.}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \section{To continue...}
        \lipsum[4-7]
        \section{To finish.}
        \lipsum[8-9]
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}

