How do I force the abstract section into one column when using a two column set-up in LaTeX?
Im using a package; style.sty, which has among other things has a part that gives me a two column lay-out for the whole document: \flushbottom \twocolumn \sloppy. This does the job with getting an automatic two-column lay-out, but it also forces the abstract section into said columns. Is there anyway of forcing the abstract to cover the whole width of the document, i.e. into a single column lay-out?
Ive tried with \usepackage{multicol}, with \onecolumn, aswell as
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      ...
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

and similar solutions, with no success.
Style.sty is the following package:
% A4 modified by Eneko; again modified by Alexander for 5cm titlebox
\setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}   % A4
\setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm}% A4
\setlength\topmargin{-0.5cm}    
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0cm}   
\setlength\textheight{24.7cm} 
\setlength\textwidth{16.0cm}
\setlength\columnsep{0.6cm}  
\newlength\titlebox 
\setlength\titlebox{5cm}
\setlength\headheight{5pt}   
\setlength\headsep{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}        
\pagestyle{empty}


\flushbottom \twocolumn \sloppy

% We're never going to need a table of contents, so just flush it to
% save space --- suggested by drstrip@sandia-2
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}

% Title stuff, taken from deproc.
\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
   \twocolumn[\@maketitle] \@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
\def\@maketitle{\vbox to \titlebox{\hsize\textwidth
 \linewidth\hsize \vskip 0.125in minus 0.125in \centering
 {\Large\bf \@title \par} \vskip 0.2in plus 1fil minus 0.1in
 {\def\and{\unskip\enspace{\rm and}\enspace}%
  \def\And{\end{tabular}\hss \egroup \hskip 1in plus 2fil 
           \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hss\egroup \hfil\hfil\egroup
          \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 0.125in
           \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
             \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}
  \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
    \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\@author 
                            \end{tabular}\hss\egroup
    \hfil\hfil\egroup}
  \vskip 0.3in plus 2fil minus 0.1in
}}

% margins for abstract
\renewenvironment{abstract}
         {\centerline{\large\bf Abstract}%
          \begin{list}{}%
             {\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.6cm}%
              \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.6cm}}%
           \item[]\ignorespaces}%
         {\unskip\end{list}}


% sections with less space
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-2.0ex plus
    -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.3ex minus .2ex}{\large\bf\raggedright}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-1.8ex plus
    -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{0.8ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf\raggedright}}
%% changed by KO to - values to get teh initial parindent right
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-1.5ex plus
   -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{0.5ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf\raggedright}}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{1.5ex plus
   0.5ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}{1.5ex plus
   0.5ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}

% Lists and paragraphs
\parindent 1em
\topsep 4pt plus 1pt minus 2pt
\partopsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
\itemsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\parsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt

\leftmargin 2em \leftmargini\leftmargin \leftmarginii 2em
\leftmarginiii 1.5em \leftmarginiv 1.0em \leftmarginv .5em \leftmarginvi .5em
\labelwidth\leftmargini\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep \labelsep 5pt

\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
   \labelwidth\leftmarginii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
   \topsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
   \parsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
   \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
    \labelwidth\leftmarginiii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
    \topsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt 
    \parsep \z@ \partopsep 0.5pt plus 0pt minus 0.5pt
    \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv{\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
     \labelwidth\leftmarginiv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv{\leftmargin\leftmarginv
     \labelwidth\leftmarginv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi{\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
     \labelwidth\leftmarginvi\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

\abovedisplayskip 7pt plus2pt minus5pt%
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip  0pt plus3pt%   
\belowdisplayshortskip  4pt plus3pt minus3pt%

% Less leading in most fonts (due to the narrow columns)
% The choices were between 1-pt and 1.5-pt leading
\def\@normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{11pt}\xpt\@xpt}
\def\small{\@setsize\small{10pt}\ixpt\@ixpt}
\def\footnotesize{\@setsize\footnotesize{10pt}\ixpt\@ixpt}
\def\scriptsize{\@setsize\scriptsize{8pt}\viipt\@viipt}
\def\tiny{\@setsize\tiny{7pt}\vipt\@vipt}
\def\large{\@setsize\large{14pt}\xiipt\@xiipt}
\def\Large{\@setsize\Large{16pt}\xivpt\@xivpt}
\def\LARGE{\@setsize\LARGE{20pt}\xviipt\@xviipt}
\def\huge{\@setsize\huge{23pt}\xxpt\@xxpt}
\def\Huge{\@setsize\Huge{28pt}\xxvpt\@xxvpt}


welcome! do https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/731931/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document?rq=1 help? style.sty is not a standard package, so we can't really guess what you're doing.

I added what the style.sty does
